# CodeMirror bad rendering on paste with custom css line-height

Tags: javascript, css, refresh, codemirror

I'm using the latest version of CodeMirror (4.12). I set the style of .CodeMirror `height:auto;` and gave viewportMargin a value of Infinity (like [Autoresize Demo](http://codemirror.net/demo/resize.html)).

Everything went fine until I decided to customize the line-height: if I set a few lines as the initial value or if I paste a large block of text, there's a margin at the bottom and the caret is not corresponding to the code. If I change the value by hitting a key or if I call `cm.refresh();`, it goes back to normal and will never create another bad rendering (until the page is reloaded).

The thing is, CodeMirror doesn't seem to provide an *oncomplete* or *on-finish-rendering* event. For now, the only way that I found is to add a few lines to the `function setDocumentHeight(cm, measure)` which seems to be the last function called when I paste something into an empty editor. Here's my code:

First, I created an object:

```
CodeMirror.prototype = {

    editorPM :
    {
        firstSetValue : false,
        firstPaste : false,
        isPasting : false
    },
    ...
```

Then I created a paste event

```
editor.getWrapperElement().addEventListener("paste", function(e)
{
    editor.editorPM.isPasting = true;
});
```

Then I added a few lines to setDocumentHeight()

```
function setDocumentHeight(cm, measure) {

    cm.display.sizer.style.minHeight = measure.docHeight + "px";
    var total = measure.docHeight + cm.display.barHeight;
    cm.display.heightForcer.style.top = total + "px";
    cm.display.gutters.style.height =
    Math.max(total + scrollGap(cm), measure.clientHeight) + "px";

    var ePM = cm.editorPM;

    if (!ePM.firstSetValue)
    {
        ePM.firstSetValue = true;
        setTimeout(function(){
        cm.refresh();
        }, 300);
    }

    if (ePM.isPasting)
    {
        ePM.isPasting = false;
        if (!ePM.firstPaste)
        {
            ePM.firstPaste = true;
            setTimeout(function(){
            cm.refresh();
            }, 300);
        }
    }
}
```

So finally, I went back to a normal line-height because I hate having to put a timeout. Still, it would be very nice to have a solution to that problem. It seems like a bug to me! And I don't like the normal line-height to code, it's too tight.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or plunkr we can look at?

Comment: I created one but it doesn't do the bug: maybe because jsFiddle (or any other) uses already CodeMirror for their app. http://jsfiddle.net/ezy9so2o/1/

Comment: Fun fact: the jsFiddle app has a custom line-height without having the rendering bug.

Comment: I also can't reproduce this, even if I move the content of your jsfiddle to a local file. Which browser does it happen on?

Comment: Really? It happens on Chrome version 40.0.2214.111

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS of your line-height in the .CodeMirror class:

```
.CodeMirror {
/* Set height, width, borders, and global font properties here */
  font-family: SourceCodePro, monospace, "Lucida Console";
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  line-height:3; // <---- Change Height Here
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know, that what I did (like I said: "Everything went fine until I decided to customize the line-height"). The point is when I do that, there's a bad rendering on paste.

Comment: Are you loading your CSS in the same order as the Fiddle?